# Proof for length of period in simple modulo $N$ sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, self-learning

I am looking for a concise proof that the length of the smallest period of the sequence
$$f[n] = a n \pmod N $$
is $N$ if $(a,N) = 1$.  From the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), it is not hard to show that $f[n]$ is periodic with $N$, but how do I know that it is not periodic with a number $M < N$.  Is a proof by contradiction the way to go?

I found a lemma in the proof of Fermat's Theorem [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048646931X), that takes me most of the way by arguing that of $1a, 2a, 3a, \ldots, (N-1)a$ are not congruent modulo $N$ if $(a,N)=1$.  This question seems so trivial and is used in discussions of the periodicity of sequences so I thought there might be several ways to show it to be true.

Comment: If $am=an$ then $a(m-n)=0$ but $(a,N)=1$ so $m=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $an=f[n]=f[0]=0\pmod N$ for some period $n$, then $N$ divides $an$. Since $a$ is coprime to $N$, $N$ divides $n$.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  This is much simpler than what I originally wrote down last night while thinking about the problem.